# Problem adding Crystal Report to VS 2005 project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

I'm trying to add a Crystal Report to a VS 2005 VB project.

Here's what I do:

- Right-click on my project, Add -> New Item ... Crystal Report
- Add a report with the standard report wizard (or just a blank report

I get this error:

```
'Site' is not a member of 'MyProject.CachedCrystalReport1'
     C:\BasProj\MyProject\MyProject\CrystalReport2.vb
```

The method in the generated code:

```
    Public Overridable Function CreateReport() As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument Implements CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport.CreateReport
    Dim rpt As CrystalReport1 = New CrystalReport1
    rpt.Site = Me.Site
    Return rpt
End Function
```

I guess somehow I told it that I want to make a website or something, but I don't know how.

I started up a fresh solution (Visual Basic Windows Application) and added a Crystal Report without any problems.

Any hints how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**  OK, something's really screwed up.  When I inspect the Me object above, it isn't even putting out the kind of object I expect.  I think I may need to piece together the solution again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:  name clash.

I was trying to move objects into the main application's project, and got rid of a subproject in the process.  When I did this, one of the classes conflicted.  That's why the Me object was all screwed up.

Comment: thanks, I had the same issue, turned out I had a class called: Component, which is also used by Crystal reports.